# W3 Slider - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, slider, typeerror

I have a failure message in my console. It says:

```
script.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at showSlides (script.js:151)
    at script.js:126
```

Its about a Slider I got from W3 School ([Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp))

I changed a bit the Code from W3 and it shows me that Message in the Console. Also if i click on one arrow in the slider this will show in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dots[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined
    showSlides http://127.0.0.1:57616/js/script.js:151
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:57616/js/script.js:126
script.js:151:5
```

I feel like I'm missing something or forgot about something to change in the JavaScript. Unfortunately I'm not that good in coding in JS.. So I hope somebody could help me with the problem! Thanks a lot!

HTML

```
 <div class="slideshow-container">
                <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-werkzeuge.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Werkzeuge</p>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-feuer.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Feuer</p>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-ziege.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Nutztiere</p>
                </div>

                <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow-container {
z-index: 20;
max-width: 400px;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 45%;
left: 45%;
background-image: url(/img/szene2-slider-BG.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%; }

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #c7113c;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.caption-text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

and JS:

```
 // SLIDER 

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no element found with  `var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");`

when try   `dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";`

it gives `error Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

may be you messing some element of `dot` class in html

I added some div of `dot` class in html now it working fine

```js
// SLIDER 

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    //console.log(slides);
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // console.log(slides);
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
     //console.log(slides);
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
z-index: 20;
max-width: 400px;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 45%;
left: 45%;
background-image: url(/img/szene2-slider-BG.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%; }

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 50%;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #c7113c;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.caption-text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
 <div class="slideshow-container">
                <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-werkzeuge.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Werkzeuge</p>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-feuer.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Feuer</p>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="/img/szene2-ziege.png" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="caption-text">Nutztiere</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="dot"> </div>
<div class="dot"> </div>
<div class="dot"> </div>
                <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It Worked!